Firebase function deploy fail after made multiple functions
When I try to deploy multiple functions, following error occur and don't have any clue to fix the issue.
Error: spawn "C:\Users\user\functions\first_update\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

I have two folder for firebase functions.
Originally I only had first_update contents inside of functions folder but since I needed to add another function, made two folder inside of functions folder. This tree are based on official document. Also modified firebase.json which is in same folder as functions.
Folder tree
functions (folder)
-first_update
--main.py
--requirements.txt
--venv (folder)
--.gitignore

-test
・・・same as first_update

firebase.json functions section
"functions": [
{
  "source": "functions/first_update",
  "codebase": "first_update",
  "ignore": [
    "venv",
    ".git",
    "firebase-debug.log",
    "firebase-debug.*.log",
    "*.local"
  ]
},
{
  "source": "functions/test",
  "codebase": "test",
  "ignore": [
    "venv",
    ".git",
    "firebase-debug.log",
    "firebase-debug.*.log",
    "*.local"
  ]
}

],
